Connect to a postgres database in e2e nestjs
Having trouble to connect to my local postgres database in e2e.
Here my docker-compose
services:
  database:
    image: postgis/postgis:13-3.1
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local


My docker compose env
DB_PASS=admin
DB_USER=admin
DB_PORT=5433
DB_NAME=test

I use this function to connect to the database
  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: this._configService.getStringOrError('DB_HOST'),
      port: this._configService.getNumberOrError('DB_PORT'),
      username: this._configService.getStringOrError('DB_USERNAME'),
      password: this._configService.getStringOrError('DB_PASSWORD'),
      database: this._configService.getStringOrError('DB_NAME'),
      synchronize: this._configService.getBooleanOrError('DB_SYNCHRONIZE'),
      dropSchema: this._configService.getBooleanOrError('DB_DROP_SCHEMA'),
      migrationsRun: this._configService.getBooleanOrError('DB_RUN_MIGRATIONS'),
      logging: this._getLogLevel(),
      maxQueryExecutionTime: this._configService.getNumberOrError('DB_QUERY_TIME_WARNING'),
      entities: this._entities,
      retryAttempts: 1,
      keepConnectionAlive: true,
      subscribers: [NullToUndefinedSubscriber],
    };
  }

I use this environment to run the app
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5433
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
DB_NAME=test
DB_SYNCHRONIZE=true
DB_DROP_SCHEMA=false
DB_RUN_MIGRATIONS=false

And this one to run e2e (found that you need to use docker service name)
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5433
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
DB_NAME=test
DB_SYNCHRONIZE=true
DB_DROP_SCHEMA=false
DB_RUN_MIGRATIONS=false

When I start the e2e I get this
// Print typeorm config
  console.log
    TYPEORM DATA {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'postgres',
      port: 5433,
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin',
      database: 'test'
    }

// Error
[Nest] 22  - 07/07/2024, 2:02:08 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN database
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
  console.log
    Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN database
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
      errno: -3001,
      code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
      syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
      hostname: 'database'
    }

First I tried with localhost but it seems the host is resolved based on the container name.. Anyway i can run the app fine with using localhost
So I'm wondering where is the issue since the database access is fine when running the app... Is it docker side or nestjs side ?
Thanks



You are aware that port 5433 isn’t the standard port for PostgreSQL? At what port number is your database listening?

I use 5433 for convenience, tried to put all to 5432 but i get the exact same result.

How are you running the application and database in the e2e environment?  You can only use the container name as a host name if the client is also running in a container, usually in the same Compose file.

(I'd also recommend removing the command: override, changing the second ports: number to the fixed standard PostgreSQL port 5432.  In this example you're not using Docker networking to connect to the database, but if you did, you'd use the standard port number, ignoring ports:.)

I run my app outside of the docker compose.
I edited the docker compose in main post. But it's still the same issue

so i shpuld just use localhost as db host since my app isn't in tje docker compose?
